# Cache strategy, AFNetworking

Tags: ios, caching, afnetworking-2

I download images and use it in my app. I have more then 100 images and I use it not all at a time. I will use cache. Then I load all images I save it to cache. Then I will go to the other parts of the app and I will use some that images.

I not really understand how the ios cache works  and I have a question: after load all images and saving it to cache, how should I use this images, I mean, I need load them from cache or use instances of images that I have before saving it ti cache ?

And what caching strategy is more useful with AFNetworking 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFNetworking has in-memory caching for images. If you have 100 images it could appropriate for you, could be not.

You should also read about NSURLCache here - http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/.

If you use NSURLCache you do not have to think about caching - when you start downloading something that is already cached, system will just give you downloaded file.

UPDATE:
Time expiration for downloaded data is set by server in response. But you can edit or ignore it by NSURLConnectionDelegate method. Example:

```
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse {

    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)[cachedResponse response];

    // Look up the cache policy used in our request
    if([connection currentRequest].cachePolicy == NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy) {
        NSDictionary *headers = [httpResponse allHeaderFields];
        NSString *cacheControl = [headers valueForKey:@"Cache-Control"];
        NSString *expires = [headers valueForKey:@"Expires"];
        if((cacheControl == nil) && (expires == nil)) {
            NSLog(@"server does not provide expiration information and we are using NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy");
            return nil; // don't cache this
        }
    }
    return cachedResponse;
}
```

Comment: Can I use NSURLCache with AFNetworking Image response?

Comment: ok, that's good, and last question until I can not accept your answer, how can I set time for storing cache?